# Domain Driven Design and Working with polymorphic Child Entities

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, soa

I have been thinking of the best approach to deal with Aggregate Entities having polymorphic children and wonder if anyone could tell me if implementation below is a correct implementation or if I may be overlooking some potential pitfalls.

The following code demonstrates a system for sending some sort of communication on varying schedules.

THE DOMAIN

```
class Delivery {
    Dictionary<Type, Func<ScheduleDto, ScheduleEntity>> ScheduleFactories = 
        new Dictionary<Type, Func<ScheduleDto, ScheduleEntity>> {
            { typeof(DailyScheduleDto), GetDailySchedule},
            { typeof(HourlyScheduleDto), GetHourlySchedule}
        };

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public StatusEnum Status { get private set; }
    public Schedule Schedule { get; private set; }

    public Delivery(DeliveryDto dto){
        Id = dto.Id;
        Message = dto.Message;
        Status = StatusEnum.New;

        Schedule = ScheduleFactories[dto.Schedule.GetType()](dto.Schedule);
    }

    public void Update(DeliveryDto dto){
        Message = dto.Message;
        Schedule.Update(dto.Schedule);
    }

    public DateTime GetNextExecution(DateTime after){
        return Schedule.GetNextExecution(after);
    }

    public enum StatusEnum { New, InProgress, Complete }

    Schedule GetDailyScheduleEntity(ScheduleDto dto){
        return new DailyScheduleEntity((DailyScheduleDto)dto);
    } 

    Schedule GetHourlyScheduleEntity(ScheduleDto dto){
        return new HourlyScheduleEntity((HourlyScheduleDto)dto);
    }  
}

abstract class Schedule {
    public DateTime StartsOn { get; private set; }

    public abstract DateTime GetNextExecution(DateTime after);

    public virtual void Update(ScheduleDto dto){
         StartsOn = dto.StartsOn;
    }

    public Schedule(ScheduleDto dto) {
        StartsOn = dto.StartsOn;
    } 
}

class DailySchedule : Schedule {
    public DaysEnum Days { get; private set; }

    public override DateTime GetNextExecution(DateTime after){
       return // logic for calculating the next day based on Days;
    }

    public DailySchedule(DailyScheduleDto dto)
        : base(dto)
    { 
        Days = dto.Days.ToEnum<DaysEnum>();
        base.Update(dto);
    }

    public override void Update(ScheduleDto dto){
        if(!(dto is DialyScheduleDto)) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        Days = ((DailyScheduleDto)dto).Days.ToEnum<DaysEnum>();
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum DaysEnum{
        Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
    }
}

class HourlySchedule : Schedule {
    public int Interval { get; private set }

    public override DateTime GetNextExecution(DateTime after){
       return // logic for calculating the next hour based on interval;  
    }

    public HourlySchedule(HourlyScheduleDto dto)
        : base(dto)
    {
         Interval = dto.Interval;
    }

    public override void Update(ScheduleDto dto){
        if(!(dto is HourlyScheduleDto)) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        Interval = ((HoulryScheduleDto)dto).Interval;
        base.Update(dto);
    } 
}

class DeliveryService : IDeliveryService {
     public void Add(DeliveryDto dto){
         var delivery = new Delivery(dto);

         var scheduledTask = new ScheduledTask(
             delivery.Id,
             delivery.GetNextExecution(after: DateTime.Now)
         );

         unitOfWork.Add<ScheduledTask>(scheduledTask);
         unitOfWork.Add<Delivery>(delivery);
         unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
     }

     public void Update(DeliveryDto dto){
          var delivery = unitOfWork.Get<Delivery>(dto.Id);
          delivery.Update(dto);
          unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
     } 

     public void SendAll(){
         var scheduledTasks = unitOfWork.GetAll<ScheduledTask>(st => st.ExecutionDateTime < DateTime.Now && st.Status == ScheduledTaskStatus.New);
         scheduledTasks.ForEach(//Send to subsystem for execution);

     }
}
```

CONTRACTS

```
public class DeliveryDto{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Message {get; set;}
    public ScheduleDto Schedule {get; set;} 
}

public class ScheduleDto{    
    public DateTime StartsOn {get; set;} 
}

public class HourlyScheduleDto : ScheduleDto{
    public int Interval {get; set;} 
}

public class DailyScheduleDto : ScheduleDto{
    public String Days {get; set;} 
}
```

I would typically have specific dtos for creating new instances and performing updates, but reuse the same types here for simplicity.

Although there is an argument that passing Dtos directly to Entities would tightly couple clients to the domain, my intention is to provide a thin facade-type layer that would be responsible for 'upgrading' dtos to maintain compatibility with existing clients should the current dto's need to change to accommodate changing business needs

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts :

- The design seems overcomplicated. `DailySchedule` and `HourlySchedule` both inherit `Schedule` but in their `Update()`methods, you have to cast the parameter to different types by hand, which is a smell that inheritance is misused there.

  Also, `Delivery` containing a Dictionary of Schedule factories seems dubious. The only reason I can see is when you have to generate multiple objects of multiple different types, but `Delivery` only seems to need one `Schedule` object.
- I see a potential bug when doing `Schedule.Update(dto.Schedule)` in `Delivery` and the schedule is not of the type that the `Delivery` was initialized with (Hourly instead of Daily or vice versa).
- Overall, the code fails to convey domain intent IMO. `Update` is vague -- what does the user need to update and for what reason ? The `after` variable name is cryptic. Why does `GetNextDeliverySchedule()` return a DateTime and not a Schedule as the name suggests ? and so on.